# Check supported architectures of framework in Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

As requested by Apple in the next February (February 2014), every app submitted to AppStore needs to support Arm64 architecture. In my project, I used many static libraries (*.a) and I can check if these libs support arm64 arch. However, I don't know if some frameworks such as Facebook.framework supports this new arch. How can I check it?

Comment: Sorry, would you like to share the reference news for the needs to support Arm64?

Comment: Hi @fattomhk, I'm sorry for that, it saids that new apps submitted to Appstore must be built using latest Xcode 5 and optimized for iOS 7, not must support arm64. But iPhone5S and latest iOS devices build on arm64 so I think we should make changes asap. This is the link: https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a

Comment: If it is the case, I would surrender for some client projects which required supporting iOS5+. I bet Apple want ios7 can run all the apps only. I would leave this issue to February, until Apple reject my updates. (OMG, if arm64 must be supported, that iOS7 UI guide....)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Each framework is really just a directory - not even like a package directory, but a plain directory you can browse directly into with Finder.  Go into the .framework folder, at the top level you'll find a file with the same name as the framework (for older frameworks that file may be located under a folder called `Versions/A` within the .framework folder).

That file is really a static library (.a) file, just without the extension.  Check it as you would any static library (using `file` or `lipo -info`) and you'll see what binaries the file contains.

You'll also know through XCode though.  If you switch your project to support arm64 and the libraries you are linking to do not have arm64 support, XCode will not finish linking when compiling for a device.

Comment: Thanks, it's true. There is a file with same name as framework that they hid the extension and I can check it now.

Comment: Yosemite's version of file can detect arm64 (confirmed)

Comment: Thanks @nick, I updated the answer to remove the out of date stuff.  It has been a while since the 64 bit transition now.

Comment: The extension isn't hidden. There simply isn't an extension. Library files within frameworks are named as raw name of the framework, with no prefix, suffix or extension.

Comment: Great answer, Thanks. I used to use 'otool -hv' for this, and had to tediously hunt for my needed architecture in the long list of Mach headers... This is beautiful and helpful.

Comment: Some frameworks do not have "Versions/A" in the folder.

Comment: @RRN good point, adjusted the answer to note that in modern frameworks the file is located at the top level of the .framework directory.

Answer (score 33):

Check below command in Terminal
`lipo -info yourlib.a`

Output like :
`Architectures in the fat file: yourlib.a are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64`

In case Framework.framework

Go to inside framework like below
`cd /Your_Path_/CocoaLumberjack.framework`

then run command
`lipo -info CocoaLumberjack`

Comment: It seems that lipo command is not working for the dynamic framework of iOS, as I was unable to execute this command for the .framework library.