# Issue with building project after addition of AFNetworking in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, xcode8

I just added AFNetworking in my project and have this problem.If you will say that I need to add a security.framework I will answer that I did it already.Here is screenshots. [Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEeHX.png)

[I have already added framework screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgiRh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On screenshot I see that you added Apple Security.framework, and problem is with AFNetworking framework. Are you sure that you added AFNetworking to your project. If it was also added - then next question comes:

Was [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) used for this, or there was another source. CocoaPods should install newest version of framework but if framework is for example copied from older project - then it can cause many issues. For example framework may not support arm64 architecture.

So first attempt to solve this problem will be using fresh version of framework (using CocoaPods recommended), eventually check architectures supported by framework (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779222/check-supported-architectures-of-framework-in-objective-c)).

Answer (score 0):

Clean your build folder and run pod install.